# Error when adding Gson library external Jar

Tags: android, gson

i would like to use the GSON library, a Java library that can be used to convert Java Objects into their JSON representation but it not works.

Properties -> Java Build Path -> Libraries -> Add External JARs (add the downloaded gson jar)

I get this error:

```
caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.gson.GsonBuilder
```

Help

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a folder call 'lib' under your project and copy the gson jar over to 'lib' directory and repeat your step above.